# Building a test for an Phonegap Barcode Plugin

Tags: cordova

I'm completely new to Phonegap and I've been trying to install the BarcodeSacanner plugin for iOS https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner It comes with a test app which I haven't been able to set up.

In the README.md file it explains how to you need to build the tests before you able to run them. However, there's this simple instruction I can't understand:

"Run `make build` in this directory."

I'm sure this is a stupidly easy thing to do but I'm not sure how to do it. How do I make to run "make build"?

I've tried with the Terminal with no sucess. Any help is really appreciated it.

Comment: what does the terminal say after you run make build?

Comment: check if it´s installed, on unix-like systems by running "which make"

Answer (score 0):

May help some people coming to view this post, I have been using Plugman to manage Cordova/PhoneGap plugins, https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman

You can install the BarcodeScanner with a command similar to:

`cd /project/directory`

`plugman install --platform ios --project platforms/ios/ --plugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner.git`